# What is the difference between auth()->loginUsingId(1); vs Auth::loginUsingId(1);

Tags: php, laravel

What is the difference between `auth()->loginUsingId(1);` vs `Auth::loginUsingId(1);`

Comment: The first, ->, is used when you want to call a method on an instance or access an instance property.

The second, ::, is used when you want to call a static method, access a static variable.

Comment: call a method through object  and call a static metod through scope resolution operator

Comment: For Laravel, there's not much any difference between those two. Because Auth is what it is called a Facade, and you can also access some Facades with a non static method: `auth()->`. You can find more information on this page. This Facades you can access with the `auth()` type are listed in the column "Service Container Binding". It is the same thing as the `view()` facade: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be no performance difference, because they do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

you will get the same results, but one of them you are calling a global function

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L136